# i am getting error in my servlet

Tags: javascript, java, jquery, html

I am a beginner in Java. I have to create a login servlet and I'm trying to run it in Tomcat 7 but my project is not running. Please help me out.

I am getting running status false in Tomcat. I have two type of users. One is admin and other is customer. When admin's related login page will show and customer will redirected to the related page customer can add client and in this customer can send bulk email to their clients. 500 email with the gap of 10 seconds how to do this.

i am getting this error in tomcat log file.
(Nov 27, 2017 5:05:19 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDirectory
SEVERE: Error deploying web application directory C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 7.0\webapps\admin
java.lang.IllegalStateException: ContainerBase.addChild: start: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[/admin]]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:898)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:871)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:615)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory(HostConfig.java:1095)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployDirectory.run(HostConfig.java:1617)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:471)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:334)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:166)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)))

[image: here is a screen shot of tomcat]

```
index.html

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
     <link rel="stylesheet" href="bootstrap/bootstrap.min.css">
     <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/cust-login.css">
      <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/pure-min.css">
      <script src="bootstrap/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<div class="header-page">

    </div>
    <div class="header-two" >       
    </div>

<br>
<br>
<div class="cust-login-form">
        <div class="cust-login-form-align">
        <form class="pure-form pure-form-stacked" method="post" action="login">
    <fieldset>
        <legend><img src="image/LOGO.png" height="50px">Custmer Login Form</legend>

        <label for="email">Email</label>
        <input id="email" type="email" placeholder="Email" name="email">
        <span class="pure-form-message">This is a required field.</span>

        <label for="password">Password</label>
        <input id="password" type="password" placeholder="Password" name="pass">



        <label for="remember" class="pure-checkbox">
            <input id="remember" type="checkbox"> Remember me
        </label>

        <button type="submit" class="pure-button pure-button-primary">Sign in</button>
    </fieldset>
</form>
</div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>


login.java

import javax.servlet.*;
import java.io.*;
import javax.servlet.http.*;
import java.sql.*;
public class login extends HttpServlet 
{
    public void doPost(HttpServletRequest req,
        HttpServletResponse res)
        throws ServletException,
        IOException
    {
        res.setContentType("text/html");
        PrintWriter pw=res.getWriter();
        String u=req.getParameter("email");
        String p=req.getParameter("pass");
        String userad="komal@gmail.com";
        String passwrd="admin";
        RequestDispatcher rd;
        try
        {
            Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
            Connection con=DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/adminpanel","root","root");
            PreparedStatement stmt=con.prepareStatement("select * from custdetails where email=? AND password=?");
            stmt.setString(1,u);
            stmt.setString(2,p);
            ResultSet rs=stmt.executeQuery();
            while(rs.next()){
        if(userad.equals(u) && passwrd.equals(p))
        {
            HttpSession session=req.getSession();
            System.out.print(session.isNew());//true
            rd=req.getRequestDispatcher("/adminpanel.html");
            rd.forward(req,res);
            return;
        }   
        else if (u.equals(rs.getString(6)) && p.equals(rs.getString(5))) {
            HttpSession session=req.getSession();
            System.out.print(session.isNew());//true
            rd=req.getRequestDispatcher("/addcustomer.html");
            rd.forward(req,res);
            return;
        }
        else{
        PrintWriter out=res.getWriter();
        out.print("Invalid user or password");
        rd=req.getRequestDispatcher("/index.html");
        rd.include(req,res);
            }
        }
    }
        catch(Exception e)
            {
                out.println(e);
            }
        }
}




regcustclnt.java

import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.http.*;
import java.io.*;
import java.sql.*;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
//import javax.servlet.http.HttpRequest;
//import javax.servlet.http.HttpResponse;

public class regcustclnt extends HttpServlet{

    public void doPost(HttpServletRequest req,HttpServletResponse res)throws ServletException,
        IOException{
        res.setContentType("text/html");
        PrintWriter out=res.getWriter();
        String name=req.getParameter("name");
        String contact=req.getParameter("contact");
        String email=req.getParameter("email");
        String address=req.getParameter("address");
        String profession=req.getParameter("profession");
        Connection con=null;
        Statement stmt=null;
        try{
            Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
            }catch(ClassNotFoundException ex){
                ex.printStackTrace();
            }
            try{
                con=DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/adminpanel","root","root");
                stmt=con.createStatement();
                String query="insert into custClientdetail values('"+name+"','"+contact+"','"+email+"','"+address+"','"+profession+"')";
                stmt.execute(query);
                out.print("<h1>you have added a new customer..!");
            }
            catch(SQLException ex){
                out.print("error in inserting data");
                ex.printStackTrace();
            }

            finally{

                try{
                    stmt.close();
                }
                catch(SQLException ex){}

                try{
                    con.close();
                }
                catch(SQLException ex){}
            }




    }
}



logout.java

import javax.servlet.*;
import java.io.*;
import javax.servlet.http.*;
public class logout extends HttpServlet 
{
    public void service(HttpServletRequest req,
        HttpServletResponse res)
        throws ServletException,
        IOException
    {
        HttpSession session=req.getSession(false);
        session.invalidate();
        RequestDispatcher rd=req.getRequestDispatcher("/index.html");
        rd.include(req,res);
    }
}


web.xml

    enter code here

<web-app>
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>login</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>login</servlet-class>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>login</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/login</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>regcustclnt</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>regcustclnt</servlet-class>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>regcustclnt</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/regcustclnt</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>logout</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>logout</servlet-class>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>logout</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/logout</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>


adminpanl.html


<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
     <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
     <link rel="stylesheet" href="bootstrap/bootstrap.min.css">
     <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css">
      <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/pure-min.css">
      <script src="bootstrap/jquery.min.js"></script>
      <script type="text/javascript" src="js/form.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

    <div class="pag-header">
        <h3><img src="image/LOGO.png" height="50px">ADMINSTRATION</h3>
    </div>

<div class="next-page-header">
        <div class="nav-menu">

            <span class="menu"><a href="admin.html">Add Customer  |&nbsp;&nbsp;</a>
            <a href="about us">View Customer  |&nbsp;&nbsp;</a>
            <a href="gallery">gallery  |&nbsp;&nbsp;</a>
            <a href="portfolio">portfolio  |&nbsp;&nbsp;</a>
            <a href="contact">contact</a>

            </span>
    <a href="logout" style="float:right">LOGOUT</a>


    </div>

    </div>
    <div class="form-header">
    <div class="cust-form">
        <h4>Add_Customer<button type="button" id="add" style="float:right;height:30%" class="btn-style">ADD</button></h4>

    </div>


    </div>

<div class="main-form-width" id="main-form" style="display:none">
    <div class="main-form">
    <form method="post" acttion="insrt" class="pure-form pure-form-aligned">
    <fieldset>
        <div class="pure-control-group">
            <label for="name">Name</label>
            <input id="name" type="text" placeholder="Name" name="name">
            <span class="pure-form-message-inline">This is a required field.</span>
        </div>
         <div class="pure-control-group">
            <label for="contact">Contact</label>
            <input id="contact" type="text" placeholder="Contact" name="contact">
            <span class="pure-form-message-inline">This is a required field.</span>
        </div>
        <div class="pure-control-group">
            <label for="uname">Username</label>
            <input id="uname" type="text" placeholder="Username" name="username">
            <span class="pure-form-message-inline">This is a required field.</span>
        </div>

        <div class="pure-control-group">
            <label for="password">Password</label>
            <input id="password" type="password" placeholder="Password" name="pass" >
        </div>

        <div class="pure-control-group">
            <label for="email">Email Address</label>
            <input id="email" type="email" placeholder="Email Address" name="email">
        </div>

        <div class="pure-control-group">
            <label for="foo">Address</label>
            <textarea id="foo" type="text" placeholder="Address"  name="address"></textarea>
        </div>
        <div class="pure-control-group">
            <label for="bname">BusinessName</label>
            <input id="bname" type="text" placeholder="BusinessName" name="bsname">
        </div>

            <div class="pure-control-group">
            <label for="logo">Logo</label>
            <input id="logo" type="file" placeholder="upload file" name="upfile">
        </div>
       <!-- <div class="pure-controls">
            <label for="cb" class="pure-checkbox">
                <input id="cb" type="checkbox"> I've read the terms and conditions
            </label>-->

            <button type="submit" class="pure-button pure-button-primary" style="margin-left:10%">Submit</button>
        </div>
    </fieldset>
</form>
    </div>

</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: https://www.wikihow.com/Ask-a-Question-on-Stack-Overflow

Comment: Are we supposed to create a project, install your code in it, run it, find a bug and fix it for you?

Comment: Please produce a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that demonstrates the problem.

Comment: yes i am creating a project but where to install this to find bugs.i am using tomcat.

Comment: can i upload my folder in stack overflow -chai T.Rex

Comment: *and in this customer can send bulk email to their clients* I'm not going to help send bulk emails. There is enough evil in the world.

Comment: no i am not evil you don't worry my purpose is to create a project for my semester and want learn. @ElliottFrisch

Comment: please help me why my project is not ruuning on tomcat showing 404 error .

Answer (score 0):

You can send mails using threads which will allow you to set the time also. Please refer multiThreading concept

Comment: ok thankyou but for now i am not able to run my project on tomcat when i click on project name it shows 404 error.i dont know what is the error.

Comment: are you getting your index page in browser?

Comment: thats the problem i am not getting index page which is html  running status is false i have add screenshot you can check folder with the name admincontrol when i click on this it shows 404 error

Comment: add welcome file in your web.xml.<welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>index.html</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>